# What does "兵器谱排行榜第一位" mean/represent?

Tags: meaning

Full sentence:

> 你们可真是兵器谱排行榜第一位，够贱

I did some googling, and it seems like "兵器谱" is a leaderboard for fictional weapons? I have absolutely no clue what this means in relation to "够贱".

[Source](http://www.17k.com/chapter/493239/11339020.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Chinese pun-like joke known as 歇后语. What they have in common is two parts, where the second part is a homophone of the expected answer to the first.

In this case, "够贱" is supposed to sound like the true answer to "兵器谱排行榜第一位". That may not be obvious at first, and I think this joke was told poorly, but my guess is that "兵器谱排行榜" actually refers to the [Eighteen Arms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eighteen_Arms_of_Wushu), of which there are four that are considered the "best" (四大兵器), which includes the 剑 or [double-edged straight sword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jian). So "够贱" is a homophone of "够剑", or "as good as Jian".

So a proper translation might be:

> You really are the first among the weapons - as good as Jian (so [despicable](http://www.zdic.net/z/25/js/8D31.htm)).

With the joke working because "jian" sounds the same as "despicable" in Chinese.

The problems with this joke are:

- There's no well-known list known as 兵器谱排行榜
- Of the lists that are well known, such as the 四大兵器, although 剑 ranks highly, it doesn't rank first

Answer (score 0):

Baike says: [兵器谱](http://baike.baidu.com/subview/583158/7042173.htm) is a fictional ranking of the best weapons and their users. I think in this context, it's a very sarcastic comment. The speaker doesn't really think these guys are very skilled. That's why he says `够贱`, which indicates what he really feels. If we give the full context of the quote:

> 宋青峰，白云飞，刘逍遥，你们三个是柳至尊的狗腿子不成，他都不来追我，你们跟过来干屁，你们可真是兵器谱排行榜第一位，够贱！

We can see the speaker is saying these 3 guys don't even pass muster as lapdogs for 柳至尊. And then the speaker says something along the lines of: `wow you guys are really the best (ranked in the leaderboards), just kidding you guys are despicable`.